# T-SQL, Select from a few tables with grouping

Tags: t-sql, select, grouping

I have really hard task and I dont know how to start.

Lets say we have tables:

```
Car
 - CarId (int)
 - OperatorId (int)
 - ProductionDate (date)

Person
 - PersonId (int)
 - Name (vchar)

CarRentHistory
 - HistoryId (int)
 - CarFk (int)
 - OperatorFk (int)
 - ChangeDate (date)
```

Every car is always rented. Date of its production is first time when it gets rented.

One person can rent same car few times, but every car can have only one operator in one moment.

The problem is how to select data for every person and every car (gruping by person and car) average time of rents.

```
Example:
Person1:    
 - PersonId = 1,
 - Name = Bill,

Person2:    
 - PersonId = 2,
 - Name = Max,

Car1:
 - CarId = 1,
 - Operator = 1,
 - ProductionDate = 2013/1/1,

CarRentHistory:    
 - HistoryId=1, CarFk=1, OperatorFk=1, Date = 2013/1/1
 - HistoryId=2, CarFk=1, OperatorFk=2, Date = 2013/2/2
 - HistoryId=3, CarFk=1, OperatorFk=1, Date = 2013/3/3
```

So Car was rented 2013/1/1 by Person1 (by Production) then mont later Person2 rented it (2013/2/2).

Result should be like that:

Bill, Car1, Average = ( (2013/2/2 - 2013/1/1) + (NOW - 2013/3/3) )/2

Max,  Car1, Average = (2013/3/3 - 2013/2/2) / 1

Please help, :(

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to find out the length of each rental period. To do that, perform a correlated subquery that finds the end date that would go with the start date. If we don't find a row, that means the rental is current and today's date would be the end date (I assume). Once you have the length of each rental, it's a simple matter of grouping by person and car and taking the average.

Here's the full query:

```
with RentalLengths as (
  select P.Name, H.CarFk,
    datediff(Day, ChangeDate,
      isnull((
        select min(ChangeDate)
        from CarRentHistory H2
        where H2.CarFk = H.CarFk
          and H2.ChangeDate > H.ChangeDate
        ), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) as Length
  from CarRentHistory H
  inner join Person P on P.PersonId = H.OperatorFk
)
select Name, CarFk, AVG(Length)
from RentalLengths
group by Name, CarFk
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25a72/13) is a SQL Fiddle showing the query in action.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question because problem has changed.  In the table Car we have additional column named CreatorFk. Its the person who is the first person who rented the car. So first date we have to check is ProductionDate + CreatorFk, then normally from CarRentHistory. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2012, you can make good use of the new LEAD windowed function. It will give you the value of a column *for the next row*, which makes it very useful to build the pairs of each rental period.

The idea is the same as Chad Henderson's answer: first build the pairs, then compute the average.

```
with RentalPeriod as (
  select
    CarFk, OperatorFk, ChangeDate, 
    lead(ChangeDate) over (partition by CarFk order by ChangeDate) as NextChangeDate
  from CarRentHistory
)
select
  CarFk, OperatorFk, 
  avg(datediff(day, 
               ChangeDate, 
               isnull(NextChangeDate, getdate()))) as AverageDays
from RentalPeriod
group by CarFk, OperatorFk
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25a72/15/0)

The result is of course the same but the execution plan is probably better.